# Makefile: Same Rule for multiple Targets

Tags: makefile

I've some targets (lets say 3). So after the makefile has run, I want to have 3 executable files.

Here's what I've done by now:

```
CC      = gcc
CFLAGS  = -Wall -pedantic -ansi

ECHO  = server_echo
ECHO_O = echo.o

FOO = server_foo
FOO_O = foo.o

ALL = $(ECHO) $(FOO)
ALL_O = ECHO_O FOO_O

all: $(ALL) 

$(ECHO): $(ECHO_O)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(ECHO) $(ECHO_O)

$(FOO): $(FOO_O)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(FOO) $(FOO_O)

.PHONY: clean
clean:         
        - rm -f $(ALL)
        - rm -f *.o
        - rm -f core

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

.PHONY: mci
mci: clean $(ALL)
```

There I've a duplicate of rules for the targets $(ECHO) and $(FOO). Is there any way, that I can eliminate the duplication? Something like:

```
for target, target_o in $(ALL), $(ALL_O)
target: target_o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o target target_o
end for
```

Or is there another way to solve my Problem?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Nothing easier:

```
$(ECHO): $(ECHO_O)
$(FOO): $(FOO_O)

$(ECHO) $(FOO):
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Or you can do away with the variables `ECHO_O` and `FOO_O` entirely with a [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern):

```
$(ECHO) $(FOO): % : %.o
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

Comment: I believe this is incorrect.  The [GNU manual](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_10.html#SEC93) says that the rule you have written means the `$(CC)` command is expected to create both `$(ECHO)` and `$(FOO)`.  Since `$(CC)` only outputs one file and not both, when you run `make`, only the first target will be produced.  If you run `make` immediately a second time, it will produce the second target.  What it won't do is run `$(CC)` twice as suggested, so it won't create both targets in a single run if neither exist already.

Comment: @Malvineous: I have tested these rules. (And that passage in the manual does not apply to a *static* pattern rule, which is not quite the same thing as a pattern rule.)

Comment: Ah, you are right.  It is not very well explained in the manual, but it seems that [static rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage) can have multiple targets listed and they work as you describe.  It didn't work for me because I was using pattern rules, and I didn't realise there was a difference.  Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 4):

For a bit larger rules, [the call function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Call-Function.html) or [canned recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Canned-Recipes.html) can be useful.

Here is an untested example with the call function:

```
define COMPILE =
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(2) $(1)
endef

$(ECHO): $(ECHO_O)
        $(call COMPILE,$^,$@)

$(FOO): $(FOO_O)
        $(call COMPILE,$^,$@)
```

Here is an untested example with a canned recipe:

```
define COMPILE =
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
endef

$(ECHO): $(ECHO_O)
        $(COMPILE)

$(FOO): $(FOO_O)
        $(COMPILE)
```

The examples contain [multi-line variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multi_002dLine.html) as well as [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).

Just in case, here is a link to the tutorial that I find useful: [link](https://makefiletutorial.com/).